# Chrome omnibar: How can I ensure that search engines are always first?

Tags: google-chrome

When I configure a search engine with a custom shortcut it will often be difficult to use, because when I type the shortcut into the omnibar it will be one of the last ones in the list, forcing me to use the arrow keys to get to it instead of tabbing.

[image: Screenshot of the situation]

Is there some way I can make a search engine (such as "Seach jQuery API for  - (Keyword: jq)" in the screenshot) to be the default on tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to, Legate. You just **type the keyword followed by a space** and the shortcut will take precedence over autofill.

---

1. Here's me starting a Creative Commons search:

   [image]
2. Here's what happens when I type the space after the *cc* keyword (keyword that you can see configured in the background):

   [image]

---

If you want to avoid conflicts with normal searches, you can start all your keywords with an hyphen, for instance. Or some other similar trick. On this case, I would have to type *-cc* followed by a space. That would avoid conflicts with any search you wanted to start with "cc".

Comment: I just ran into a minor annoyance with this: I created the shortcut "css", but now if I want to search for something beginning with "css " the shortcut is activated instead. So I guess I'll have to make sure my shortcuts are never sequences I might search for? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: @Legate Well, what I have setup at home is my keywords actually beginning with an hyphen. On your case, that would be "-css". I find it more intuitive and it won't clash with regular searches.

Comment: An update to this - The advice given (to continue with a space to get the shortcut to take precendence) is no longer working for me, as of today (using v29/Linux). It now seems that once the term is in your search history that takes precedence (standard location bar search history, not the shared-between-browsers "Google History").